# Using Geometry commands in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, intersection, st-geometry

I am looking to find the most effect way to use SDE and ST_Geometry SQL commands.

Can anyone tell me how/what commands I might use to perform a spatial query in MS Sql Server 2008, to Select property parcels that are contained by or cross the boundary of a flood area layer?

I then have to export the result (containing, owner, and address details) to some format that can be used to do a mail out. I would also have to create a site specific map for each property affected. Showing the neighbourhood parcels, specific owners parcel, flood potential layer and roads.

Comment: I would be think to use sde.st_intersects within a SQL statement.

Comment: What have you tried as a result of research? There's certainly a dozen primers on the web from which to start.

Comment: Note that there is no SDE.ST_GEOMETRY implementation on SQL-Server, so you can only use Microsoft's datatype(s), and it's primers on GEOMETRY and GEOGRAPHY that you need to review.